# BINARY MULTIPLICATION ALGORITHM PROOF

Tags: binary

So there is a multiplication trick It says 
   9×13 say
Half and double everything 
4.5×26
Cancel out the .5 
4×26
2×52
1×104
Cancel out the even left hindsight multipliers and add the left right hand numbers

So 9×13= 104+13 = 117
I know how this can be explained by working in binary .Is there a rigorous proof how this algorithm works in binary.

Comment: Was your caps lock key stuck during the title?  You have not explained the algorithm clearly.  What is a left hindsight multiplier?  It looks like you want some numbers above other ones.

Comment: The 'trick' is known as [Russian peasant and/or ancient Egyptian multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication) method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of Russian Peasant Multiplication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099095/proof-of-russian-peasant-multiplication)

Comment: Yes thank a lot